# Length of string after delimiter in the data inside a file

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a ton of data files that have delimiters inside and I would like to know the max length of the column after each delimiter. Since I can't to use a third-party program, I would like to get this done through PowerShell as that is built-in for Windows. And, at the same time I can't manually do. So, wondering if this could be achieved with PowerShell at all or any simple trick to do so?

Here is my sample data in a file FOO.TXT

> Col1|Col2|Col3
>
> 12345|This is a String|This is another String
>
> 45688|String|This is another String of unknown length
>
> 30098|Second Column String|Third Column String

**Expected output:**

> Col1 Max Length - 5
>
> Col2 Max Length - 20
>
> Col3 Max Length - 40

Comment: the `Import-Csv` cmdlet has a `-Delimiter` parameter ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Sorry, I am fairly new to PowerShell. Would you be able to provide the code that does the magic please? Thanks!

Comment: it looks like `Vad` has shown you the idea. for more info, Read The Friendly Manual -> `Get-Help Import-Csv -Parameter Delimiter` and `Get-Help Import-Csv -Examples` are good places to start. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this(but file with data must have csv extension):

```
$j=Import-Csv -Delimiter "|" -Path D:\testdir\new.csv #import our csv as array string
$colums=$j|gm -MemberType NoteProperty|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name #get columns name
Foreach($colum in $colums){
$l=($j."$colum"|Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum #for each column get max length
Write-Host $colum" Max Length- "$l
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helped. However, I see that it is sorting the results in alphabetical order of the column names instead of showing them as they appear in the file. Is it possible to show the column results in the same order as they appear in the file?

Comment: it's not sorting, just first column named "col1" second "col2" thats why it's look's like sorting.It runs from first column to last

Comment: @Julaayi Yes, getting the column names using `Get-Member` does sort the columns and is not getting you the headers in the order as they appear in the file. To get them in the exact same order, use `$columns = $j[0].PSObject.Properties.Name` instead. As aside, the file may have any extension you want. Normally for a CSV file this would be `.csv`, but the `Import-Csv` cmdlet does not really care about that. `.txt` or `.blah` will import just fine as long as the content is parsable csv. What **does** matter is that the file does not start with empty lines.

Comment: @Theo Thank you very much for that explanation! That did work with both the order as well as the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I was looking for irrespective of the file extension. Thanks to both @Vad and @Theo.

```
$j=Import-Csv -Delimiter "|" -Path D:\testdir\FOO.TXT #import our csv as array string
$columns = $j[0].PSObject.Properties.Name #get columns name
Foreach($column in $columns){
$l=($j."$column"|Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum #for each column get max length
Write-Host $column" Max Length- "$l
}
```